# My image doesn't show up at the top of website, issue with aligning?

Tags: html, css

Here's the screenshot of my issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSVQj.png, as you can see here, the quote doesn't align to the top of the website, and I don't know why it happens. Any solutions? Here's the code:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"> <img src="media/images/logo.png"> </div>

  <div style="background: #000; width: 440px; height: 344px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95); -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95); box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95); text-align: justify; display: inline-block;"> <img src="media/images/covers/comingsoon.png"></div> <!-- YOUTUBE -->

  <div style="background: #000; width: 410px; height: 125px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95); -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95); box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95); text-align: justify; display: inline-block;"><h1 style="margin: 10px;">"The sky above the port was the color of television, tuned to a dead channel."</h1></div> <!-- QUOTE -->

  <div style="background: #000; width: 405px; height: 125px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95); -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95); box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95); display: inline-block;"> <a href="http://breathlessrpg.com/"> <img width="400px" src="media/images/covers/breathless.png"> </a> </div> <!-- BREATHLESS -->

  <div style="background: #000; width: 405px; height: 125px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95); -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95); box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95); display: inline-block;"> <a href="http://breathlessrpg.com/"> <img width="400px" src="media/images/covers/breathless.png"> </a> </div> <!-- BREATHLESS -->

  <div style="background: #000 url(http://38.media.tumblr.com/c24cbbf9efaed9992839b7feca83f9be/tumblr_nlzqeuNbDp1slaspwo2_500.gif); width: 860px; height: 212px; text-align: center; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95); -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95); box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95); margin: 0px auto;"><img src="media/images/covers/secret.png"></div> <!-- SECRET_SOCIETY -->

</div>
</body>
```

I want the quote to be right next to comingsoon.png box, and then the rest of images below.

Comment: try `vertical-align: top;` in the div where the quote resides.

Comment: First issue fixed (http://i.imgur.com/oM5snzh.png), how to make the rest of images go under the quote? (because there is some free space there)

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the browser's default margin or padding, usually around 16px, has not been overwritten.

Try adding the below to your CSS:

```
html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Not the case. :/
body {
 color: #bbbae8;
 font-family: "ff";
 margin: 0px; 
 padding: 0px; 
 border: 0px;
 background: #000000 url(http://static.tumblr.com/ca0b171c1b7a3f4bc83941025b2b3539/pztnjat/soDn5bmq3/tumblr_static_5fo5mlrj44so0004c84swk00g.jpg);
}

Comment: I would also add * to the selector, so html, body, * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

Comment: Added, but the issue still occurs.